# nuget package manager version issue VS 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, nuget

I am using VS 2013 and .Net 4.5/4.6. I am not getting this error message:

```
The 'System.Collections 4.0.10' package requires NuGet client version '3.0' or above, but the current NuGet version is '2.8.60723.765'.
```

My understanding is that this is due to a ddl that use a higher version of .Net. Just curious is there a way to fix this (e.g. determine the responsibel dll[s])?

Comment: Presume you mean *now* rather than *not* in your question above? Any luck yet? I've just started getting this myself.

Answer (score 0):

Those packages are primarily designed for .NET Core ecosystem,

https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Collections/4.0.10

That means it should not be used for .NET 4.5 and Visual Studio 2013. I guess that's probably why Microsoft only releases NuGet 3.* for Visual Studio 2015. It makes sense to avoid polluting Visual Studio 2013 users with the brand new bits.

Comment: Exactly, hence I would like to find the dependency/reference/dll which triggers the need for 3.0!

Comment: @csetzkorn post your packages.config or project.json with your question.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to specify a version of a NuGet your client is actually compatible with.

i.e.
`System.Collections Version=x.x.x` picking of course a slightly older version than the latest one.

Answer (score -1):

You need to update your nuget package manager.

You can download the latest version over here:

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/4ec1526c-4a8c-4a84-b702-b21a8f5293ca

Comment: This one is version 2.8.7. I would need 3.0 - see error message

Comment: I can't as I use VS 2013! See Lex Li's answer.